# MS Excel: Dynamic usage of structured/table references

Tags: excel, syntax, excel-formula

Let's say `Table1` in `Sheet1` has columns `colA`, `colB`, and `irrelevant`. (My real table has a lot more columns, of course.)

In `Sheet2`, Column A has this:

```
colA
colB
```

I'd like Column B of my sheet to have the median of the column referenced in its row, so right now my `Sheet2` looks like:

```
A    B
colA =MEDIAN(Table1[colA])
colB =MEDIAN(Table1[colB])
```

Obviously it'd be nice for the column names to not be absolutely referenced in column B's formulas, but I'm not sure how to make the structured reference in column B point to the string in column A.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use INDIRECT:

```
=MEDIAN(INDIRECT("Table1[" & A1 & "]"))
```